# Deploying an Apache Nifi cluster on Debian virtual machines

Tags: debian, apache-nifi

I am asked to deploy a nifi cluster on debian virtual machines, and can't find any ressource that clearly explains how to do it. Do someone have a good resource about that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are resources for configuring an Apache NiFi cluster in the [Admin Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#clustering). A good [walkthrough by Pierre Villard is available here](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/), although it was written for 1.0.0 and the current release is 1.6.0, so there are some minor configuration changes.

I don't like posting "link-only" answers, but the instructions for setting up a complete cluster are too long and don't belong here.

Comment: Thank you for these links, the admin guide should be of great help. I was not asking more!